# Where can I find a Netbeans nightly build?

Tags: 10.10, apt, ppa, repository, netbeans

Is there any chance to install nightly Netbeans via apt?
I'd like to get daily updates to newest versions.

Any PPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following link, i hope it helps a bit:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=netbeans

Comment: Just FYI none of the versions in the searched ppas are up to date or newer than the one in the main repo, with most being at 6.5 instead of 6.9.1 (most recent stable), dev, or nightly